# how to gain text data and table data from docx in Linux using Java?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j

My project needs to read some data from docx, such as text data or table data.
These data which is needed to be read is specified by my project manager.

How can I read these data exactly? should I convert docx to xml and read xml file using dom4j? How to convert using Java? Or We have some better ways?

Comment: Have you heard about Apache POI - https://poi.apache.org/. You can also read .docx file into a text file by reading it manually using Apache POI or Docx4J and turn all the data into same format (Text or Table) and then read it all.

Comment: The best way to read it using docx4j (or POI for that matter) is going to depend on exactly what you want to do.  For example, you could read the content list (block by block), or use XPath, or retrieve specific tables which you have tagged somehow (eg with a caption, in a content control, or using bookmarks).  If you can update your question with more detail on what you are trying to achieve, you might get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Buffered Reader like this.

```
public boolean readWriteCSVFile()
 {
        boolean flag = false;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get("");
            File file = new File(path.toAbsolutePath() + "//writeCSVFile.csv");
FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            flag = true;
            br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path.toAbsolutePath() + "//ReadCSV.csv")));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] readLineSequence = line.split(",");
                ReadWriteCSVFile rd = new ReadWriteCSVFile();
                rd.writeCSVFile(line+"\r\n", fop);              
                for (String readLine : readLineSequence) {
                 System.out.print(readLine+",");
                }
            }
            fop.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            flag = false;
            System.out.println(" Exception Occured while reading CSV file ");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception Inside finally : " + ex);
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```